# Unable to cache iPad when added to home screen

Tags: ipad, caching, ios6, web, cache-manifest

I have been working on a web app that should run offline and be accessible by clicking an icon on the home screen (iPad iOS 6.1.3). The problem is that I am not able to cache all the necessary files. Here's my `cache.manifest` file (paths are correct, no type'os):

```
CACHE MANIFEST
CACHE:
index.php
first.html
second.html
images/forward.png
images/backward.png
images/info.png
style/light.otf
style/main.css
scripts/main.js
NETWORK:
*
```

The HTML's included are the next pages. So, am I right: I have to include all the required .php, .html, .css, .png, etc. in the `index.php` which is my entry point. I read some articles about this and also created .htaccess file:

```
AddType text/cache-manifest .manifest
```

Implementation in HTML:

```
<html manifest="cache.manifest">
```

Error:

```
"...because it is not connected to the internet"
```

I have been stuck in this for a few days. Any help would be great!
Thanks in advance